# How to remove extra option in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to add new field in prestashop product backoffice. For this I try many solution for this and I successfully added new fields . But I don't know how to a extra option showing . Now I want to remove this field. I searched in my all custom modules file. But this option not found . Where I remove this option . Please find attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The option that you have shown in the screenshot is added by hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra hook in PrestaShop 1.7

You should search for the same by using the following keyword:

n hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra(

Search this in all your module files and you will surely find out the module causing the problem.